# Automatize automatic error recovery

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.8.15-rt10, libfranka 0.5.0, franka_ros 0.6.0

I'm working with a Franka Emika Panda ([docs](https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/franka_ros.html)) and trying to setup a way for the robot to automatically recover from an error state. I implemented a simple action client to call the service for automatic error recovery and I would like to send the goal automatically if the robot is in an error state.

Being an error, I can't try-catch it like I would with an exception. I found that robot_state.current_errors (from franka::RobotState) is an array that's either empty or has the name of the errors at that moment and thought to use that for an if condition to trigger the service call. I have two issues here:

- I want to iterate through the list of errors for cosmetic purposes to print them and coming from python I thought of a for-in-loop like for (const franka::Errors& e : robot_state.current_errors.iterator()) but I can't manage use it. Is it because it's not implemented for the franka::Errors class?
- I can't figure out where to get the robot state from: I can't instantiate a franka::Robot because that is already controlled by the franka_control_node; this node doens't seem to provide a way to get the state or something, however franka_hw::FrankaStateInterface does have a getRobotState() from the FrankaStateHandle, which I don't know how to get.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304378/automatize-automatic-error-recovery/) by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 589 on 2018-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`franka_msgs::RobotState` is and was published by `/franka_control` on topic `/franka_state_controller/franka_states`, however that ended up being not that useful since at that time it was missing a way to see if the robot was in an error state at that moment. I was still missing a piece of the puzzle, and ended up opening an [issue](https://github.com/frankaemika/franka_ros/issues/32). The devs showed 2 ways to proceed and shortly after my post added RobotMode, which ended up being what I'm currently using.

To answer the quetion, then, I added a private `franka_msgs::FrankaState::ConstPtr current_franka_state_constptr_;`, updated via subscriber callback, and:

- opened a [related question](https://answers.ros.org/question/306488/print-subset-of-message/) and ended up with:

```cpp
uint8_t counter = 0;
for (auto it = &current_franka_state_constptr_->last_motion_errors.joint_position_limits_violation;
     it != &current_franka_state_constptr_->last_motion_errors.instability_detected;
     ++it, ++counter)
{
  if (*it)
  {
    ROS_ERROR(" - %s", name_franka_errors_[counter].c_str());
  }
}
```

- used the added robot mode for error recovery (done with an action client as franka emika suggests [in the docs](https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/franka_ros.html#franka-control)):

```cpp
if (current_franka_state_constptr_->robot_mode == franka_msgs::FrankaState::ROBOT_MODE_REFLEX)
{
  recoverFromErrors();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2018-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0